# Customize Committee page in Tabular Form

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to draw following customize table of committee members in latex. How can I draw this in latex?

[image]

I am trying to use following code but its not working.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{3cm}}
\multirow{2}{5cm}{Member and Advisor} &  \\\cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
\multirow{2}{*}{Chairman} &  \\\cline{2-2}
                                    & Academic title....\\[1em]
\multirow{2}{*}{Member and Advisor} &  \\\cline{2-2}
                                    & Academic title....\\[1em]
\multirow{2}{*}{Member} &  \\\cline{2-2}
                                    & Academic title....
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]